How can I seal a disused chimney thimble?
I had an oil fired water heater and an oil fired furnace in the basement.  Each had its own vent and thimble into the chimney.  I upgraded the water heater (HPWH) and I have removed the old water heater.  The metal thimble coming of the brick chimney (lined with clay) is still there.  What is the best way to cover/seal this thimble?  The furnace will still be used.

Also How to properly close a chimney hole in the basement.
